# What is the difference between class and cssClass property in spring form

Tags: html, css, class, spring-form

Below is the usage of **class** and **cssClass**. I am a newbie to Spring and confused between the two class properties. why don't we use just **class** in the place of **cssClass**

```
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="label.employeeName" /></td>
                <td><springForm:input path="employeeName" class="form-text" /></td>
                <td><springForm:errors path="employeeName" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSSClass is an ASP.Net property for ASP.NET controls. Class is an html attribute. The CSSClass property is rendered as Class in html. Interestingly, you can specify multi-class in CSSClass property in the same manner as the Class - separated by a space.